# Can an EJB bean implement multiple interfaces?

Tags: java, interface, javabeans, ejb-3.1

Can an EJB bean implement multiple user defined interfaces, except business interfaces (@Local, @Remote) or No-Interface view (@LocalBean)?

For example define two interfaces `UserInterface1`, `UserInterface2`, with no annotation.

Is this legal to implement:

```
@Stateless
public class MyBean implements UserInterface1, UserInterface2 { ...
```

Then I have another confusion:

```
@Stateless
public class MyBean implements Runnable { ...
//inside I won't try to manage thread
}
```

Is this legal or illegal, I found that glassfish support this situation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The given example is illegal, but nevertheless accepted by quite some implementations (application servers).

David Blevins started [a thread about](http://java.net/projects/ejb-spec/lists/jsr345-experts/archive/2012-06/message/0) this on the EJB mailing list a while ago.

EJB 3.2 will make the rules more clear for this topic. See [What's new in EJB 3.2 ? - Java EE 7 chugging along!](https://blogs.oracle.com/arungupta/entry/what_s_new_in_ejb) (look for section *Simplified the rules to define all local/remote views of the bean*)

Comment: what if I just implement one interface (still without any annotation)? That interface could be user defined or interface from some java packages(for example java.lang.) is this implementation illegal?

Comment: 1 interface seems to be legal without using any annotations. See http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/Local.html

Comment: The answer is good, though it doesn't answer the topic question, to which I would respond, "yes, an EJB can implement multiple interfaces, but in that case, you must explicitly specify which interfaces are business interfaces using `@Local` or ejb-jar.xml".

Comment: @bkail the topic title says "multiple interfaces", but the post opens with asking for multiple interfaces, **except business interfaces**. Unfortunately the situation with mixing (multiple) business interfaces and (multiple) regular interfaces is not that clear.

Comment: Even considering David's post, the semantics seem quite clear when (non-empty) `@Local` is specified on the bean class. Anyway, if OP is satisfied, that's all that matters :-).