# Spring Bean implementing multiple interfaces

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, inject

I have a bean which implements two interfaces. The barebones code is as follows:

```
interface InterfaceA {
  ...
}

interface InterfaceB {
  ...
}

public class ClassC implements InterfaceA, InterfaceB {
  ...
}
```

In my AppConfig I am specifying the following:

```
@Bean(name = "InterfaceA")
public InterfaceA interfaceA() {
    return new ClassC();
}

@Bean(name = "InterfaceB")
public InterfaceB interfaceB() {
    return new ClassC();
}
```

And I use it so:

```
public class MyClass {

    @Inject
    private final InterfaceA a;

    public MyClass(@Named("InterfaceA") InterfaceA a) {
        this.a = a;
    }
     ...
}
```

However, Spring complains that:

> No qualifying bean of type
>   [com.example.InterfaceA] is
>   defined: expected single matching bean but found 2:
>   InterfaceA, InterfaceB

Similar question was asked and answered for EJB [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13986223/341008) but I could not find anything for Spring beans. Anybody know the reason?

The workaround is to introduce a new interface which extends both `InterfaceA` and `InterfaceB` and then let `ClassC` implement that. However, I am loath to change my design because of framework constraints.

Comment: Why... Just create a single instance of `ClassC`... The return type of the method doesn't matter here, as the bean will be both `InterfaceA` and `InterfaceB`. You don't need an additional interface...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spring is right ... When you write

```
@Bean(name = "InterfaceA")
public InterfaceA interfaceA() {
    return new ClassC();
}

@Bean(name = "InterfaceB")
public InterfaceB interfaceB() {
    return new ClassC();
}
```

Spring creates to `ClassC` objects, one named `InterfaceA`, the other `InterfaceB`, both implementing InterfaceA and InterfaceB.

Then when you write :

```
@Inject
private final InterfaceA a;
```

you ask Spring to find a bean *implementing* `InterfaceA`, but as said above there are 2 so the error.

You could either create only one object of type `ClassC`, or use `@Qualifier` or `@Named` annotations :

```
@Inject
@Named("InterfaceA")
private final InterfaceA a;
```

That way, you explicitely ask Spring to find the bean *named* `InterfaceA`, and hopefuly it is now unique.

Comment: Thanks. Adding `@Named` to the field fixed it. I will accept your answer. However, I did annotate the constructor parameter with `@Named`. Why was that not sufficient? Didn't that tell Spring to use the correct bean?

Comment: @341008 : If you bean creation uses the constructor with the `@Named` annotation, it should work ... provided you remove the `@Inject` on `a` attribute. If not, as soon as the `MyClass` object is constructed, Spring honours the `@Inject` annotation and tries to set  `a` with a `InterfaceA` bean and finds 2 of them.

Comment: Oh, I see. I was setting `@Named` for the constructor parameter and `@Inject` on the field. I will have to remove `@Inject` then. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Thank you for your excellent question.

In my case, I created an interface that extends both A and B:

```
public interface InterfaceC extends InterfaceA, InterfaceB {}
```

... and the common implementation implements the unified interface:

```
public class ClassC implements InterfaceC {
  //...
}
```

This unified interface allows then to create a single bean:

```
@Bean
public InterfaceC implementationForAandB() {
    return new ClassC();
}
```

The Spring framework is then able to inject or autowire the common implementation to dependencies expressed in terms of the primary interfaces:

```
public class MyClass {

    @Inject
    private final InterfaceA a;

    @Inject
    private final InterfaceB b;

    public MyClass(InterfaceA a, InterfaceB b) {
        //...
    }
```

}