# Stateless EJB implements interface injection failed

Tags: java, ejb, wildfly-8, weld

Wildfly 8.2.0

I have a `Stateless` EJB and an interface.

```
@Local
@Stateless
public class Bean implements IBean{
...
}

@Local
public interface IBean {
...
}
```

But I get a WELD Error. If Bean doesn't implement the interface there is no errors. According to  https://stackoverflow.com/a/13988450/2023524
and https://blogs.oracle.com/arungupta/entry/what_s_new_in_ejb there should be no error.

Error:

```
WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type Bean with qualifiers @Default
  at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject private mypackage.anotherBean.bean
```

**Update**: 
I've tried all possible combinations with `Local` but it doesn't help. Only if interface is removed there is no error.

```
@Stateless
public class Bean implements IBean{
...
}

@Local
public interface IBean {
...
}

//*****************************
@Stateless
public class Bean implements IBean{
...
}

public interface IBean {
...
}
//************************************
@Local
@Stateless
public class Bean implements IBean{
...
}

public interface IBean {
...
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you want to inject a bean whether by EJB (using `@EJB`) or CDI (using `@Inject`) container you declare a  variable with interface type. Concrete implementation of declared interface is found by a container during application deployment. In your example the problem is not with annotations but with a declared type being injected (`Bean` instead of `IBean`).

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove `@Local` from Bean.

```
@Stateless
public class Bean implements IBean{
...
}
```

Because you define 2 possible Local WELD doesn't know which one to use.

The oracle documentation show this too with `@Remote` interface:

```
@Remote
public interface Foo { . . . }

@Stateless
public class Bean implements Foo, Bar {
    . . .
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But it doesn't help. See question update.