# Implement interface with multiple EJBs

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, java-8, ejb

Given the following interface:

```
public interface MyRunnable {   
    public MyResponse run(int x);
}
```

It is implemented by two `@Stateless` beans:

```
@Stateless
public class Bean1 implements MyRunnable {

     public MyResponse run(int x) {
           // some logic
     }
}


@Stateless
public class Bean2 implements MyRunnable {

     public MyResponse run(int x) {
           // some logic
     }
}
```

Now, I want to run one bean or the other depending on a condition. What is the best way to achieve that?

This is what I tried, unsuccessfully:

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class MainBean {

   @Inject 
   private Bean1 bean1;

   @Inject 
   private Bean2 bean2;

   public void someMethod(int y) {

          MyRunnable runnable = null;
          if (y == 1)
              runnable = bean1;
          else
              runnable = bean2;

          runnable.run(5);

   }
}
```

The code compiles, but it gives me (in Wildfly) a startup error:

> WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type Bean1 with
>   qualifiers @Default

**UPDATE** 
Something that I noticed; if I remove `implements MyRunnable` from the beans there are no startup errors.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stateless EJB implements interface injection failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34352909/stateless-ejb-implements-interface-injection-failed)

Comment: @Flown the question you are referring to only deals with one bean, in my case it is multiple. Do you know how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you're implementing the same interface in `Bean1` and `Bean2` they are mapped to to `MyRunnable` (they are now `@Local` beans). Since Weld does not know how to resolve this you would need to specify which bean you would like to inject. The proper way would be:

```
@Stateless
public class MyBean {

  @EJB(beanName = "Bean1")
  MyRunnable bean1;

  @EJB(beanName = "Bean2")
  MyRunnable bean2;

  public void run() {
    MyRunnable r = Math.random() < 0.5d ? bean1 : bean2;
    r.run(10);
  }
}
```