# Can I CDI-1.0 or -2.0-inject multiple interfaces implemented by one Stateless EJB?

Tags: jakarta-ee, cdi, ejb-3.0, ejb-3.2

Like in the following example:

```
public interface CommandLineDieselEngineExhaustManipulatorService{
    // command line services
}
public interface ClientDieselEngineExhaustManipulatorFacade{
    // ui-client services
}


@Stateless
public class DieselEngineExhaustManipulatorImpl  implements CommandLineDieselEngineExhaustManipulatorService, ClientDieselEngineExhausManipulatorFacade {
    // Implementation of both interfaces
}

@Stateless
public class MyCdiManagedClass{

    @Inject 
    private CommandLineDieselEngineExhaustManipulatorService cliService;

    @Inject
    private ClientDieselEngineExhausManipulatorFacade clientFacade;

    // Whatever
}
```

I am not interested your opinion in whether or not I should favour the injection of plain Stateless EJBs (without interface) over Stateless EJBs injectable by its implementing interface.

I tried with JEE7 (CDI1) without success. I got the impression that EJB+CDI does not support that.

I wonder if it possible with JEE8?

I could not find any part in the CDI 2.0 specification, which seems to give a hint in the direction. I would highly appreciate if someone could point to the right place.

This Question did not answer the injection part either, might be outdated and the interesting link is dead:  [Can an EJB bean implement multiple interfaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13986223/can-an-ejb-bean-implement-multiple-interfaces)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, first of all, CDI is not the bad guy here - in fact, from CDI viewpoint, having a bean with two interfaces, you can inject two beans based on those interfaces without problems.

**The real deal seems to be EJB**. Now, I am not sure what application server are you running and what EJB version (you tagged question as `ejb-3.0` but talk about Java EE 7 which would be EJB 3.2).

From EJB 3.1 specification, section 4.9.7 Session Bean’s Business Interface:

> If the bean does not expose any other client views (Local, Remote, No-Interface, 2.x Remote Home, 2.x Local Home, Web Service) and the bean class implements a single interface, that interface is assumed to be the business interface of the bean. This business interface will be a local interface unless the interface is designated as a remote business interface by use of the Remote annotation on the bean class or interface or by means of the deployment descriptor.

Long story's short - **Multiple interfaces are not supported in EJB 3.1.**
That being said, some servers might support it?

However, moving on to EJB 3.2, again section 4.9.7 Session Bean’s Business Interface:

> If the bean class is annotated with the Local
>    annotation, or if the bean class is annotated with neither the Local
>    nor the Remote annotation, all implemented interfaces (excluding the nterf
>   aces listed above) are assumed to be local business interfaces of the bean.

Therefore, **in EJB 3.2, it is supported. Note that just below this text there is an example with exactly your case.**

So I guess your problem boils down to:

- *What application server do you use?*
- *What EJB version does the server have?*

Comment: We are operating within a Wildfly 10 (wildfly-javaee7-10.1.1.Final) , which implements JEE7, i.e. I refer to EJB 3.2.  Thanks so far for your references. I will take a glimpse into Section 4.9.7 of the EJB Spec.

Comment: @ChristianKoelle could you add the stack of the error you are getting?

Comment: I added the code depicted in the question to an example application and it works like charm. - So question answered. Thx ---- I don't not know anymore, what caused injection erros in the past and how the stacktrace was, but I can confirm that it generally works.